# Hibernate returns wrong result set and generates wrong query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a table which can referance on itself.

```
organisation(id,child_from_Org, ...)
```

Hibernate Mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organisation")
public class Organisation implements java.io.Serializable {

  private Integer id;
  private Organisation organisation;
  private ...

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "child_from_Org")
  public Organisation getOrganisation() {
    return this.organisation;
  }

  public void setOrganisation(Organisation organisation) {
    this.organisation = organisation;
  }
  ...
}
```

If i execute a a hibernate query like "from Organisation", then i'll get all organisations.

```
from Organisation o where o.id = 1
```

Then i get the organisation with id 1

```
from Organisation o where o.id = 1 or o.organisation.id = 1
```

Returns organisation with id 1 and all child organisations

```
from Organisation o where o.id = 1 or o.organisation.id = 1 or o.organisation.organisation.id = 1
```

Does not return the organisation with id 1!!!! Why?
I tried all possible combinations with braclets (() or () or ()).

I looks like a wrong SQL is getting generated from hibernate:

```
select  organisati0_.id as id470_,
  organisati0_.child_from_Org as ist21_470_,70_,
  ,...
 from
  organisation organisati0_ cross 
 join
  organisation organisati1_ 
 where
  organisati0_.child_from_Org=organisati1_.id 
  and (
   organisati0_.id=1 
   or organisati0_.child_from_Org=1 
   or organisati1_.child_from_Org=1
  )
```

How can i resolve that problem?

Comment: Show us organisation mapping.

Comment: I have updated the question with the mapping.

Comment: Also adding table definition will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have an implicit join from `Organisation` to itself, and in hibernate implicit joins are inner joins:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms

> The implicit form does not use the join keyword. Instead, the associations are "dereferenced" using dot-notation. implicit joins can appear in any of the HQL clauses. implicit join result in inner joins in the resulting SQL statement.

Try explicit left joins, e.g.:

```
select o from Organisation as o left join o.organisation as parent left join parent.organisation as grandparent where o.id = 1 or parent.id = 1 or grandparent.id = 1
```

(**NOTE:** I've assumed organization.organisation is a parent relationship.  If that's not the case you can(and should) replace the `parent` and `grandparent` aliases with something more appropriate)

**EDITED TO ADD:**

It seems what's happening is that the inner join is ruling out org with id of 1, probably because org with id of 1 has a null `organisation`

**EDITED AGAIN TO ADD:**
Added select per comment below.

Comment: Thank you it works, i thought that hibernate should automatically generate a left join.

Comment: I have edited your query with an explicit select: `select o from Organisation o left join o.organisation as parent left join parent.organisation as grandparent where o.id = 1 or parent.id = 1 or grandparent.id = 1`. Otherwise hibernate also returns parent and grandparent.